# How to call a layout in container on button click (in Navigation Drawer)

Tags: android, xamarin, navigation-drawer

I want to load a layout on button click as shown in picture [image]

The click event of button I get here

```
 #region OnClick of Account button
        ImageView Account_Button = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.accountbutton);
        Account_Button.Click += delegate
        {
            //code
        };
        return view;

        #endregion
```

So I want that in container I want to load a layout, please suggest me how I do?

Comment: Good to see your are going against android design patterns

Comment: ohh seriously, is this against android design patterns???

Comment: If I load the contains in drawer itself then is that against android design patterns??? please suggest

Comment: You design is against android design pattern, see how beautiful android NavigationView looks. and what have you done to that beauty
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=NavigationView+android&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju37HV0bXKAhWCA44KHYW5CiMQ_AUIBygB&biw=1855&bih=995

Comment: please elaborate, what is wrong? top tabs or bottom buttons??

Comment: ohh :(... this designs are aproved by client, please suggest if you have any suggestions

Comment: if its is like that then tell you client that nobody would even look at your app even once in their lifetime

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101065/discussion-between-sumit-pathak-and-sector11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer

```
#region OnClick of account button
        ImageView acc_Button = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.accountbutton_orange);
        acc_Button.Click += delegate
        {
            OnClick();
        };

        #endregion
```

and call

```
public void OnClick()
    {
        FragmentTransaction ft;
        Fragment frag;

        frag = new SlidingTabsFragment();
        ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        ft.Replace(Resource.Id.sample_content_fragment, frag);
        ft.AddToBackStack(null);
        ft.Commit();
    }
```